# What is the best way to generate unique number in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

What is the best way to What is the best way to generate unique number in Laravel? Is there standard function from box to generate unique number in Laravel?

Comment: What is your use case? A unique number? Do you mean a unique string? There is no way you can possibly generate a unique number, more than once, and still be within acceptable levels of how unique it really is; unless you setup a database to store previously generated.

Comment: http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: I mean number like as: 48923

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you're trying to accomplish with this, but here's a stab at it.

Create a `Number` model with the following schema:

```
Schema::create('numbers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

Leverage its auto-increment ID as your unique number. These will be sequential, not random numbers.

```
$number = App\Number::create();
$number->id; // a guaranteed unique number
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try with php `uniqid()` too.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: "This function does not guarantee uniqueness of return value." Plus, it doesn't give numbers - they're alphanumeric.